# grant SQLPermission and permission to connect to the database in policy file java

Tags: java, permissions, policy

How to grant `SQLPermission` to a `codebase` in Java? I am trying to connect to a database (MySql) using JDBC.

The only helpful information I found was at [SQLPermission](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html#SQLPermission) even which was not clear enough.

Do I have to grant `Socket` permission along with it?

policy file I have used

```
  grant 
{

permission java.net.SocketPermission "*", "listen, connect, accept";
permission java.sql.SQLPermission "setLog";
permission java.sql.SQLPermission "callAbort";
permission java.sql.SQLPermission "setSyncFactory";
permission java.sql.SQLPermission "setNetworkTimeout";

};
```

statck trace:

```
Exception in thread "Abandoned connection cleanup thread" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setContextClassLoader")
```

when I add 
permission `java.lang.RuntimePermission "setContextClassLoader";` to the policy file there are no exception but the Connection and Statement are not created are always null.On debugging the application jumps directly to `return flag;`at the end of try block after `conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);`

Of course everything works perfectly when security manager is not set or when AllPermission is granted.

```
public boolean validate(String name,String password) 
       {
       Connection conn = null;
       Statement stmt = null;
       try{
         System.out.println("retrieving data");
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
          System.out.println("Connection successful");
          stmt = conn.createStatement();
          String sql;
          sql = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
          while(rs.next())
          {

             String userName = rs.getString("userName");
                  System.out.println(userName+" "+name);
             if(name.equals(userName))
             {
            String pwd=rs.getString("pass");
                System.out.println(pwd+" "+password);
            if(pwd.equalsIgnoreCase(password))
            {
             String position = rs.getString("position");
                 flag=true;
                map.put("userName", userName) ;
                map.put("password", pwd) ;
                map.put("position", position) ;
                System.out.println(map);
                System.out.println("user authenticated");
            }
            }


          }

          rs.close();
          stmt.close();
          conn.close();
          return flag;
       }catch(SQLException se)
       {

          se.printStackTrace();
               System.out.println(se.getMessage());
          return flag;
       }finally
       {

          try
              {
             if(stmt!=null)
                stmt.close();
          }catch(SQLException se2)
          {
                  se2.printStackTrace();
                  System.out.println(se2.getMessage());
          }
          try
              {
             if(conn!=null)
                conn.close();
          }
              catch(SQLException se)
          {
             se.printStackTrace();
          }
          return flag;
       }
```

Comment: Run your application with -Djava.security.debug=access,failure and you will see exactly what permissions are required and absent.

Comment: @EJP:I have added System.setProperty( "java.security.debug", "access,failure" ); before setting the security manager.

Comment: @EJP: could u confirm whether the SQLPermission I have added to the policy file will be sufficient for connecting and retrieving data from the database.Can I use permission java.sql.SQLPermission "*";

Answer (score 0):

Ya indeed the problem was with permission to connect to the database.Things work fine with the new policy file.

```
grant 
{

 permission java.net.SocketPermission "*", "accept, connect, listen, resolve";
 permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read, write";
 permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "*";

};
```